# Notice: Undefined index: Page in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\achive\nur.php on line 16

Tags: pagination

First page showing:

> Notice: Undefined index: Page in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\achive\nur.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Page in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\achive\nur.php on line 17.....

```
<?php

if($_GET["txtKeyword"] != "")
    {
    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("gnnursury");
    // Search By Name or Email
    
    $strSQL = "select @rownum:=@rownum+1 rank,stid,roll,tmark,name from mark, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r WHERE (year LIKE '%".$_GET["txtKeyword"]."%')";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
    $Num_Rows = mysql_num_rows($objQuery);


    $Per_Page = 6;   // Per Page

    $Page = $_GET["Page"];
    if(!$_GET["Page"])
    {
        $Page=1;
    }

    $Prev_Page = $Page-1;
    $Next_Page = $Page+1;

    $Page_Start = (($Per_Page*$Page)-$Per_Page);
    if($Num_Rows<=$Per_Page)
    {
        $Num_Pages =1;
    }
    else if(($Num_Rows % $Per_Page)==0)
    {
        $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page) ;
    }
    else
    {
        $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page)+1;
        $Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages;
    }


    $strSQL .="order  by tmark ASC LIMIT $Page_Start , $Per_Page";
    $objQuery  = mysql_query($strSQL);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a

> **GET** parameter **Page**

and you are directly referencing it in line 17 `$Page = $_GET["Page"];`

Ideally for this easy fix will be

```
    if(!$_GET["Page"])
    {
        $Page=1;
    }
   else{
       $Page = $_GET["Page"]; 
   }
```

Hope it helps

Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use php function [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check a argument "Page" is set.

```
if (isset($_GET['Page'])) {
 $Page = $_GET['Page'];
} else {
 $Page = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update these lines

```
$Page = $_GET["Page"];
if(!$_GET["Page"])
{
    $Page=1;
}
```

With

```
if(isset($_GET["Page"] && !empty($_GET['Page'])))
{
    $Page=$_GET["Page"];;
}else{
    $Page=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass any "Page" parameter. You can change the code to.

```
if(!isset($_GET["Page"]))
{
    $Page=1;
}
```